# NumPy change elements in a specific row that match a criteria

Tags: python, numpy

So I have a matrix and I want to apply a conditional change on a certain column only.

Example:

```
array([[ 0.15293227, -1.50167614, -1.04974543],
       [ 1.25396778,  0.21520081,  0.39136217],
       [-1.1272423 ,  1.18971277,  0.19569736]])
```

Now how to set all the elements in the last column that are greater than 0 to 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach

```
In [2]: a[:, -1] = a[:, -1] > 0

In [3]: a
Out[3]: 
array([[ 0.15293227, -1.50167614,  0.        ],
       [ 1.25396778,  0.21520081,  1.        ],
       [-1.1272423 ,  1.18971277,  1.        ]])
```

and if you don't want for the negative entries to be set to zero, here is a facetious alternative:

```
In [4]: a[:, -1] = a[:, -1] ** (a[:, -1] < 0)

In [5]: a
Out[5]: 
array([[ 0.15293227, -1.50167614, -1.04974543],
       [ 1.25396778,  0.21520081,  1.        ],
       [-1.1272423 ,  1.18971277,  1.        ]])
```

In response to your comment, let's say you want to set up a custom float value to be inserted just at the positive entries (while leaving the negative entries alone).

```
In [6]: float_to_insert_at_positives = 3.14159

In [7]: (float_to_insert_at_positives - a[:, -1]) * (a[:, -1] > 0) + a[:, -1]

Out[7]: array([-1.04974543,  3.14159   ,  3.14159   ])

In [8]: a[:, -1] = (float_to_insert_at_positives - a[:, -1]) * (a[:, -1] > 0) + 
... a[:, -1]

In [9]: a
Out[9]: 
array([[ 0.15293227, -1.50167614, -1.04974543],
       [ 1.25396778,  0.21520081,  3.14159   ],
       [-1.1272423 ,  1.18971277,  3.14159   ]])
```

Comment: When the left-side argument to the `**` operator is a NumPy `ndarray`, then `**` means to raise each element of the left side array to the power given by the corresponding element of the right-side array (or, raise everything to the same power if only a scalar exponent value is given). In regular Python `**` means exponentiation for numeric types. `2 ** 3` is two cubed.

Comment: Ahh I see. So you second method would only work if I want them to be set to 1 because `x ** 0 == 1`. Is there any way to be able to set them to any other float?

Comment: I added that case as a final example.

Comment: Perfect. It took me a moment to figure out how it was working. Thanks. Building on your solution, I find this slightly more intuitive `(ar[:, -1]>0) * num + (ar[:, -1]<0) * ar[:, -1]`

Comment: Yeah, that is probably more readable, at the cost of doing two vectorized multiplies, rather than one (which probably doesn't matter most of the time).

Answer (score 3):

Current answers look overcomplicated. It can be done much easier by combining boolean and 'normal' indexing.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([[ 0.15293227, -1.50167614, -1.04974543],
   ...:               [ 1.25396778,  0.21520081,  0.39136217],
   ...:               [-1.1272423 ,  1.18971277,  0.19569736]])
```

Boolean array with your condition for the last column:

```
In [3]: mask = a[:, -1] > 0.
   ...: mask
Out[3]: array([False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Now, using combination of boolean array with slicing to assign the value you want:

```
In [4]: a[mask, -1] = 1
   ...: a
   ...: 
Out[4]: 
array([[ 0.15293227, -1.50167614, -1.04974543],
       [ 1.25396778,  0.21520081,  1.        ],
       [-1.1272423 ,  1.18971277,  1.        ]])
```

More on indexing with numpy can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
import numpy as np
list_1=np.array([[ 0.15293227, -1.50167614, -1.04974543],
       [ 1.25396778,  0.21520081,  0.39136217],
       [-1.1272423 ,  1.18971277,  0.19569736]])

for i in list_1:
    if i[-1:][0]>0:
        i[i.tolist().index(i[-1:])]=1

print(list_1)
```

output:

```
[[ 0.15293227 -1.50167614 -1.04974543]
 [ 1.25396778  0.21520081  1.        ]
 [-1.1272423   1.18971277  1.        ]]
```

> Just for fun in one line you can do something like this:

```
[i.__setitem__(i.tolist().index(i[-1:]),1) for i in list_1 if i[-1:][0]>0]
```

output:

```
[[ 0.15293227 -1.50167614 -1.04974543]
 [ 1.25396778  0.21520081  1.        ]
 [-1.1272423   1.18971277  1.        ]]
```

Comment: Whoah man. List comprehension is supposed to make core more readable and understandable.... that is not. Putting a for look there doesn't always make things better. Thanks anyways! I like the first solution though.